# PHP radio button not posting correctly

Tags: php, html

I'm stuck in a bit of a pickle I can't figure out. Any help is appreciated.

I set up an HTML radio table

```html
<div class="radio-group">
 <label class="heading">Choose your game</label><br/>

<table>
 <tr>
  <td>
  <input type="radio" name="radio" value="Radio 1"> Radio 1
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
  <input type="radio" name="radio" value="Radio 2"> Radio 2
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
  <input type="radio" name="radio" value="Radio 3"> Radio 3
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr> 
  <td>
  <input type="radio" name="radio" value="Radio 4"> Radio 4
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
</div>
   </br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
  <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset"/>
    
 </form>
</div>
```

My PHP page will POST the correct selection, but loads other stuff it shouldn't.  How do I differentiate between the radio selections if there are all the same name? If I name it separately, you can click on every selection.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

if(isset($_POST['radio']))
{echo '<iframe etc etc></iframe>;
}
else{echo '<iframe other></iframe>;}
}
```

Comment: What "other stuff" is it sending?

Comment: I want each selection to load its separate iframe.  I haven't put the code in yet but no matter what selection I pick it loads the first iframe.

Comment: @JohnDoe Refer to the answer I posted John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check what value was posted and then make your echo statement based on that. Here's an example of two radio buttons in the same group and name

```
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="1"> Radio 1
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="2"> Radio 2
```

and here is the PHP to see which one has been submitted

```
if(isset($_POST['radio'])) {
    $value = $_POST['radio'];
    if($value == "1") {
        echo "SOMETHING HERE FOR VALUE 1";
    } elseif($value == "2") {
        echo "SOMETHING HERE FOR VALUE 2";
    }
}
```

Notice how the value is set to something simple like an integer, it makes it easier to check it later on and then display the appropriate or desired outcome for that selected button :)

Comment: It worked perfectly, you are my hero!  Something so simple but wasn't sure if I should be using an array instead.  Thanks again!

Comment: No problem bud, if you have any more questions you can post them or message me directly for help

Comment: If you have many of these values, a `switch/case` is probably a cleaner solution. http://php.net/switch - or using the value directly instead of doing close to the same thing many times. Just a tip ;-)